# Most efficient data structure for sorting an ArrayList by categorical factors

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, processing-efficiency, space-efficiency

I have created an object, let's call it EventObject, that will hold the results of an SQL query. Initially the objects will be aggregated into a single ArrayList. I am trying to develop a method that will look at each EventObject in the ArrayList, and if it equals a given value of a categorical factor, copies it to another group.

For example, if a Timestamp value for EventObject1 falls on a Sunday, copy the object into a Sunday level of a Weekday factor; if that same Timestamp falls in the month of May, copy it into a May level of a Month factor as well, etc.

I am stuck as to what type of data structure(s) would be most efficient for sorting. I do not know how many EventObject will fall into a level of a given factor, and the number of factors to be analyzed will be dependent upon an ID I pass to the method. It is required that I will have K factors, each with a known number of levels; and each level can have any number of EventObjects after the soring occurs.

Should I attempt to hold all factors together in a single ArrayList? This requires a 3 dimensional structure. Would it be more prudent to create a separate data structure for each factor?

Comment: How many total event objects will you have?  I suspect that keeping them all in one ArrayList, and sorting on each factor will be efficient enough.

Comment: So, if I understand the question correctly, your goal is to create something that is more efficient than the standard library sort?

Comment: You use the word "sort" everywhere, but you don't seem to actually want sorting. You seem to want to group objects together. by days, months, etc. So it seems you just need a `Map<Month, List<EventObject>>`, and a `Map<Day, List<EventObject>>`. Try doing it, and then see if you need to optimize anything. You probably won't.

Comment: Gilbert Le Blanc and Manu, I misspoke. I am attempting to group objects into separate collections so that I can quickly and easily store a set of event objects by several categorical factors. JB Nizel, your Map suggestion will definitely work. Thanks for your help.